# My conditional join

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with my SQL request, if I have 2 results, I need the result from fr05 and only this one.

```
SELECT sad.*, pl.*
FROM SalesAndDistrib AS sad 
INNER JOIN Price_List AS pl ON pl.VKORGAU = sad.VBAK_VKORG 
                            AND sad.VBAP_MATNR = pl.MATNR 
                            AND pl.WERKS in ('FR27', 'FR05')
```

I can't solve this properly.
Thank you for your help
Best Regards

Comment: Which dbms are you working with? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, etc. Please tag accordingly.

Comment: Also some sample data and desired results will go a long way.

Comment: in this case you could use `order by pl.WERKS` and fetch only first result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all non tested code as I need a dataset to run this against.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT sad.*, 
               pl.*, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY vbap_matnr 
                   ORDER BY PL.werks ASC) AS row_num 
        FROM   salesanddistrib AS sad 
        INNER JOIN price_list AS pl 
                ON pl.vkorgau = sad.vbak_vkorg 
               AND sad.vbap_matnr = pl.matnr 
               AND pl.werks IN ( 'FR27', 'FR05' )) AS bob 
WHERE  bob.row_num = 1
```

What this will do is use the [Over Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) to group all records by pl.werks.
Then selecting the top 1 *should* give you the fr05 record, as fr05 comes before fr27

Comment: probably partition should be over `sad.VBAP_MATNR` not `WERKS`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza why do you say that?

Comment: Because `VBAP_MATNR` is some kind of ID and for each id he can have  `('FR27','FR05')` and OP want preference for each `'FR05'` in your query you only return one random `'FR05'`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thank you very much, i updated the answer

Comment: because format I didnt realize there is double join condition. The partition should be `PARTITION BY VKORGAU, VBAP_MATNR` But I will leave to OP debug his own code. The main idea is there.

Comment: thank you guys i have the main idea, i will work on it. i hoped i could find something easier :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will be fairly universal.

```
select top (1) sad.*, pl.*
FROM  SalesAndDistrib AS sad 
INNER JOIN Price_List AS pl 
ON pl.VKORGAU = sad.VBAK_VKORG 
AND sad.VBAP_MATNR = pl.MATNR and pl.WERKS in ('FR27','FR05')
Order by pl.werks. --add asc or desc as required
```

Comment: no there is a lot of line in salesanddistrib , but i didn't tell it ,

Comment: This is not standard SQL. @oupepasa: You still haven't told us which DBMS you are using. This answer is T-SQL (SQL Server).